# Using an abstract class as a value in an unordered_map

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting an abstract class to compile properly using an abstract class as the value. Ideally I would like to do something like the following

```
unordered_map<string, Process_Base> func_map;
```

Where Process_Base looks like

```
//Contained in Process_Base.hpp
class Process_Base{

public:
    virtual ~Process_Base(){};
    virtual void process() const = 0;

};
```

and subclasses would look something like

```
#include "Process_Base.hpp"

class Process_Message : public Process_Base {

public:
    ~Process_Message(){};
    virtual void process();

};

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Process_Base.hpp"

class Process_Message{

public: 
    void process(){
        printf("%s", "Hello");
    }
};
```

The idea behind this was I would be able to add subclasses to the map and have a simple function that would look at a key value and call the subclass' process function.

When I compile on CentOS 5.8 using

```
g++44 -Wall -c -std=c++0x -I/usr/include -g Source.cpp
```

I get the following series of errors

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/char_traits.h:41,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/string:42,
             from Source.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base>’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_function.h:482:   instantiated from ‘std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base> >’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/tr1_impl/hashtable_policy.h:790:   instantiated from ‘std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base> >, std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/tr1_impl/hashtable:137:   instantiated from ‘std::_Hashtable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base> >, std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::hash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/tr1_impl/unordered_map:48:   instantiated from ‘std::__unordered_map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base, std::hash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base> >, false>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/tr1_impl/unordered_map:190:   instantiated from ‘std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base, std::hash<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base> > >’
Source.cpp:14:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:73: error: cannot declare field ‘std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Process_Base>::second’ to be of abstract type ‘Process_Base’
Process_Base.hpp:1: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Process_Base’:
Process_Base.hpp:5: note:       virtual void Process_Base::process() const
make: *** [Source.o] Error 1
```

Can someone help me make sense of these compiler errors. Would it be better to try to make a map of function pointers rather than subclasses? If so how would I create a map of pointers to the functions in classes like Process Message.

Comment: Change it to `unordered_map<string, Process_Base*>`. You can only have pointers to abstract classes.

Comment: When I do that I get a different error of *Source.cpp:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token*

Comment: You'll have to include Source.cpp around line 14 in your post if you want help on that (or else point out which file Source.cpp is if it's already there).

Comment: You can disregard my previous comment, it was a spelling error on my part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Abstract classes can't be instantiated directly, but you can have pointers to them whose values end up being instantiated (non-abstract) subclasses.

```
class Abstract {
 public:
  virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

Abstract x;   // error
Abstract* p;  // fine

class Derived : Abstract {
 public:
  virtual void Foo() {
    printf("Hello!\n");
  }
};

p = new Derived();

// or:
Derived d;
p = &d;
```

For this reason you also can't have containers of abstract classes -- only pointers to abstract classes.

```
unordered_map<string, Process_Base*> func_map;
```

Depending on how you were populating (or trying to populate) your original `func_map`, it might be beneficial to use `unique_ptr`s instead of regular pointers.

```
unoredered_map<string, unique_ptr<Process_Base>> func_map;
```

This way you can do things like `func_map["foo"] = new Derived()` and not worry about explicitly calling `delete func_map["foo"]`.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this is an excellent case in which to use a smart pointer like boost::shared_ptr<Abstract> so that you don't have to worry about the lifetime of the Abstract objects.

Comment: Abstract must, of course, have a virtual destructor!

Comment: or std::unique_ptr which is in C++11 and guarantees clear ownership semantics.

Comment: @DaleWilson I'm not sure what makes smart pointers more/less useful in the context of abstract classes?

Comment: @alecbenzer My point about using smart pointers is that the original question is about putting values in an unordered map.  If rather than the actual values, you are putting pointers to heap allocated values (`Abstract *p = new Derived;`) then you should somewhere have a `delete p` or you will leak memory.   Making this `boost::shared_ptr<Abstract> p(new Derived);` and making it a map of smart pointers solves the lifetime issue.